# Is there (emergent) higher form spontaneous symmetry breaking in classical statistical field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

I was wondering if there are examples of (emergent) higher form spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) in classical statistical physics (finite temperature). I believe the deconfined phase of gauge theories can be interpreted this way, but I am interested in systems with local degrees of freedom (no gauge structure), and without fine-tuning, as lattice gauge theory without gauge structure will also show a phase transition, but it is very fine-tuned.

Can the BKT transition be understood this way?

I would prefer to think about spin models with discrete phase space per unit volume, but examples with continuous symmetry are also accepted.

Answer (score 3):

In BKT phase transition there is no spontaneous symmetry breaking due to short-range couplings + low dimensionality (2D). This directly related to Mermin-Wagner theorem, which states that SSB can not occur for short-range couplings in $D\leq 2$, where $D$ is the dimensionality of a system.

One way to deal with is to consider long-range interactions. To illustrate this, let me first write down the Hamiltonian of (global) $\mathrm{O}(2)$ model in 2D, which is  known as XY-model,
$$H=-J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\cos(\phi_i-\phi_j),$$
here $J>0$ is the coupling constant and $\langle i,j\rangle$ denotes the summation over nearest-neighbors of site $i$. It is the textbook model and you can find detailed discussion of BKT transition easily (for instance, you can check book by A. Altland & B. Simons or lecture notes by C. Mudry, both books are easy to find, just write names of authors and add "statistical field theory").

In order to have SSB, one can consider the long-range interactions, i.e.
$$H=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j}J(r)\cos\left(\phi_i-\phi_j\right),$$
where $J(r)$ depends on the distance between site $i$ and $j$, here $r=|{\bf r}_i-{\bf r}_j|$ is the distance. The long-range interactions means that in the limit of $r\rightarrow \infty$ the function $J(r)$ behaves as
$$J(r)\sim Jr^{-2-\sigma},$$
where $\sigma>0$. For such long-range interaction, Mermin-Wagner theorem does not hold and the following happens:

- For $\sigma>2$ the system behaves like usual XY-model with BKT phase transition
- For $1<\sigma<2$ at low $T$ the model exhibits SSB and has non-zero magnetization, whereas for high $T$ magnetization vanishes via the first-order phase transition
- For $0<\sigma<1$ the topological defects completely suppressed by long-range interactions and SSB occurs at any $T$

More detailed discussion is represented in [the recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.11810) by G. Giachetti with coauthors.

P.S.: to be honest, I do not understand properly what is "higher form spontaneous symmetry", there are a lot of different spin models, where SSB occur at finite $T$. If possilbe, could you clarify this moment?

**Addendum**

Having checked your reference in the comment below, let me draw your attention onto the following:

- Polyakov's book about gauge fields and strings, where the compact QED is discussed. Compact QED is very similar theory to described above XY-model. Also, you can check Y. Shnir book "Magnetic monopoles" for more detailed discussion. Your guess about BKT is reasonable because compact QED is indeed very similar to XY-model
- Review by J. Kogut, "An introduction to lattice gauge theory & spin systems"
- Also, you can be interested in Elitzur theorem

Comment: Thanks, your comment about Mermin-Wagner has convinced me that BKT is not an example of spontaneous breaking of higher form symmetry. 

Higher form symmetry is a generalized notion of symmetry where the symmetry acts only on p-dimensional submanifolds of space, where p < d. It is discussed thoroughly in this review article https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.03045, but as far as I know it is usually discussed in the context of quantum systems.

Comment: Comment about your addendum: all the examples you cite are "gauge theories", which do not have a local phase space (it is a local phase space with gauge equivalence classes, which makes it non-local). I know deconfined phases of gauge theories can be thought of as higher-form SSB, but I was looking for an example with a local phase space as explicitly stated in my question, like the Ising model or XY model for example.

Comment: @NandagopalManoj , I have added these references only due to the fact that Polyakov & Kogut discuss non only "gauge theories" but non-gauged, too (as I remember)

Comment: Ok thanks, I will take a more detailed look!

Comment: @NandagopalManoj , also, did you see https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.08066 ?

Comment: That's interesting! Do you think that is relevant for this question?